# subir imagenes con php en mysql

Tags: php, imagen

hola buenas estoy estudiando php y en el curso no me enseña muy bien como subir imagenes solo me pone un codigo que no me funciona es porque me falta algo como la conexion ala bd ? porque cuando subo la imagen me sale The requested URL was not found on this server.

```
<?php
$ok = '';
if ($_POST["acc"] == "subir") {
// si venimos del formulario sacamos los datos
// del archivo
$tamano = $_FILES["archivo"]["size"];
$tipo = $_FILES["archivo"]["type"];
$archivo = $_FILES["archivo"]["name"];
if ($archivo != "") {
//guardamos el archivo en el raíz siempre que
//no venga vacío
//lo llamamos 'nuevo_' y el nombre que tuviera
//en el ordenador
$destino = "/nuevo_".$archivo;
if (copy($_FILES["archivo"]["tmp_name"],$destino)) {
$ok = 'Archivo subido: si';
} else {
$ok = 'Archivo subido: no';
}
} else {
$ok = 'no se selecciono archivo';
}
}
?>
<html>
<body><p>
<?php echo $ok ?>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/
form-data">
<input name="archivo" type="file" size="35" />
<input name="enviar" type="submit" value="Subir fichero" />
<input name="acc" type="hidden" value="subir" />
</form>
</p></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Es evidente que si quieres usar la base de datos tendrás que conectarte a ella. Aunque las imágenes pueden guardarse también en carpetas... Sea como sea, el error que refieres lo que dice es que intentas usar una URL que no existe.

Comment: En ese extracto de código no estás usando ninguna conexión a BBDD. Al estar el campo action del form vacío, la URL a la que estás intentando acceder es la misma que la de la página donde se muestra el formulario por primera vez. Si te ha cargado la primera vez es que existe. Si no se puede volver a cargar, probablemente sea porque el archivo no se ha podido copiar y se haya producido un error.

Answer (score 0):

Tu error esta en el `action` del formulario html , todo el codigo php colocalo en otro archivo php y en el `action` del form colocas el nombre de ese archivo php que creaste y listo . Siempre separa el codigo , no trabajes siempre dentro del mismo archivo ya que se vuelve ilegible e inmantenible .